# Return JQuery objects into DOM using Append

Tags: jquery, append

I have created a function createFileSelect() which creates elements:

```
function createFileSelect() {

    var fSpan = $("<span/>",
        {
            "id" : "fileUpload-span",
            "class" : "btn btn-add",
            "text" : "Add a file.."
        }); 

    var fInput = $("<input/>", {
        "type": "file",
        "name": "files[]",
        "id": "fileUpload"       
    });

    return $(fSpan + fInput);
}
```

Then I call this using:

```
$("#fileUpload-holder").append(createFileSelect());
```

However, I am getting an error

```
Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [object Object][object Object]
```

How can I get this working with the (2) elements into the dom using a function?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the return statement to use jQuery's [`.add`](http://api.jquery.com/add/) method:

```
return fSpan.add(fInput);
```

---

If you want the `input` within the `span`, use this instead:

```
return fSpan.append(fInput);
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your following line:

```
return $(fSpan + fInput);
```

for this one:

```
return fSpan.add(fInput);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `+` operator is not defined for objects in javascript, so they are coerced to strings first (which is the `"[object Object][object Object]"` string). Then, as you pass the string to the `$` function, it tries to interpret it as HTML, which in turn generates the syntax error you are seeing.

To merge two jQuery objects together, you can use the [`.add()`](http://api.jquery.com/add/) function, that returns a new object that contains both:

```
return fSpan.add(fInput);
```